# Opening emacsclient -n -c opens a small frame with small fonts

Tags: window, frames, fonts

I had set up a `emacs --daemon` at the OS startup and whenever I try to open `emacsclient -n -c` emacs opens a small window (possibly the minimum size possible) and with unreadable fonts (they are too small). A following picture shows the emacs window in perspective when opened with `emacsclient -n -c`

[image: Small emacs window with small fonts]

However, if I try to open an emacs frame on the default OS terminal (`emacsclient -t`) it works perfectly:

[image: Emacs frame on a terminal]

Whats wrong with emacs? I use Prelude and I have a `.Xdefaults` file containing `Emacs.font: Ubuntu-10` that specify which font to use, but that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Is it any different from how Emacs looks when you run it graphically without a daemon?

Comment: Yes, totally normal

Comment: Can you reproduce this if you start Emacs with `emacs --daemon -q`? If not, post your init file.

Comment: @Gilles it can’t be reproduced with `emacs --daemon -q`. Something in my init file maybe? I’m  using prelude fwiw, and the init file is entirely made of prelude code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem, and it was because I was setting the font in my init file using

```
(set-frame-font FONT nil t)
```

which is closely related to GaryO's answer. Using

```
(setq default-frame-alist '((font . FONT)))
```

**Note:** make sure that you replace `FONT` with you desired font name that is already installed on your system.
solved it for me.

Comment: `set-frame-font` indeed only applies to *existing* frames (as documented in the docstring).

Comment: This was exactly my problem; I had a set-frame-font declaration in my `init.el` which caused the problem after I moved to using emacs in daemon-mode.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, but this is the correct answer for me.

Answer (score 4):

I've gotten this too. I think it's because when emacs is started in daemon mode, `window-system` is nil while reading your `.emacs`. You're probably setting up your `default-frame-alist` with something like `(if window-system (...))` which won't work in daemon mode. Do it in a hook on `after-make-frame-functions` instead; that hook function takes the new frame as an arg.